# Leverage browser caching in PageSpeed Insights

Tags: pagespeed

How can fix Leverage browser caching in PageSpeed Insights?

> Leverage browser caching Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in
>   the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load
>   previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the
>   network. Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable
>   resources: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-72668528-4
>   (15 minutes) https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

[image]

My .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"


  # Data interchange

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/calendar                         "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"


  # JavaScript

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"


  # Manifest files

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Markdown

    ExpiresByType text/markdown                         "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Media files

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"


  # Web fonts

    # Collection
    ExpiresByType font/collection                       "access plus 1 month"

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                              "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                              "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                            "access plus 1 month"


  # Other

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>
```

My system is Wordpress
Host apache

Answer (score 1):

***Browser caching for .htaccess***

The code below tells browsers what to cache and how long to "remember" it. It should be added to the top of your .htaccess file.

add below content on new file

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Save the .htaccess file and then refresh your webpage.
https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html